# how to stop dataURL from being actual url?

Tags: javascript, html, data-url

My question may seem weird as I am not sure how to phrase it!!! The problem is that I have written a function in js

```
function onSavePNG(url){
    var save =  document.createElement('a');
    console.log('url in save function'+url);
    save.href = url;
    console.log('save.href'+save.href);
    save.target = '_blank';
    save.download = 'Slide no '+(i+1)+'.png' || 'unknown';
    var event = document.createEvent('Event');
    event.initEvent('click', true, true);
    save.dispatchEvent(event);
    (window.URL || window.webkitURL).revokeObjectURL(save.href);
}
```

The argument 'url' is a dataURL from a canvas, the function is supposed to save the image to the disk. save.href is not holding the actual dataURL, It has changed to

```
'http://localhost:3000/data:image/png;base64.......'
```

and I am getting no file.
What should I do so that this

```
'http://localhost:3000/'
```

does not become the part of dataURL assigned to save.href?

Comment: Have you tried simply finding the index of `'/data:image'`... and removing everything before it?

Comment: @Lugia101101 no I haven't, but the console.log(url) shows no signs of this addition in url, how did it appear in save.href? :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved my problem by removing the single quotes appearing at the beginning and end of the dataURL

```
function onSavePNG(url){
    var save = document.createElement('a');
    console.log(url[0]+'  '+url[url.length-1]);
    url = url.slice(1);
    url = url.substring(0,url.length-1);
    console.log(url[0]+'  '+url[url.length-1]);
    save.href = url;
    save.target = '_blank';
    save.download = 'Image.png' || 'unknown';
    var event = document.createEvent('Event');
    event.initEvent('click', true, true);
    save.dispatchEvent(event);
    (window.URL || window.webkitURL).revokeObjectURL(save.href);
}
```

It's working now :)

Answer (score 0):

since `save` is an `<a>` element, just using `save.pathname` (just the path) instead of `save.href` (whole URL) in the last line of your code should do the trick.

Comment: yeah I did the same save.href = url;  then (window.URL || window.webkitURL).revokeObjectURL(save.pathname); but it's not working